# wordpress working by domain name but not by ip

Tags: wordpress, domain-name, virtual-host

I am having a hard time with a wordpress, if I am accessing it by moneythehardway.com it does display everything properly.

But if I am trying to access by 37.59.126.247/money it does display with strange behavior.

I did setup a VirtualHost (with limited knowledge) and the redirection seems to work but I don't know why in the ip access case, the display is broken.

Any help or suggestion would be perfect

Comment: define "broken".  a screenshot would be useful

Comment: You can directly try to access 37.59.126.247/money and moneythehardwah.com to compare

Comment: yes, i saw a 404 error.  That looks to me like you didn't set something up correctly.  I want to know what YOU see

Comment: I see the exact same thing as you Page not found on the title tag. And the slider is broken with a W-P-L-O-C-K-E-R things and the display is totally wrong too